# Unknown error on using .ajax() to get JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I'm trying to get a JSON file from a URL with the following jQuery code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/example.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    cache: true,
    crossDomain: true
});
```

However, when the request fires, Firebug indicates that an error occurred but doesn't tell me what it was.

I can get to the URL in my browser with no problems and the JSON is perfectly valid (according to http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html).

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Ok, changing the `contentType` to `jsonp` has gotten me a step further. My JSON looks like this (http://pastebin.com/hSAP30zv), but Firebug is saying:

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
"item" : {
^
```

Any more suggestions?

Comment: Test it on chrome and check console, maybe error message will be more accurate.

Comment: How are you hoping to achieve `crossDomain`? If you're hoping to use JSONP, you need to emit a JSONP response rather than JSON. If you're using CORS, you should pass `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` instead (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I'm not sure how well `dataType: 'json'` and `crossDomain: true` work together. You only need to use `crossDomain: true` if you want to **enforce** cross-domain behavior on the **same** domain. So, I assume that you actually really make a cross-domain request, which returns JSON. That won't work unless the server supports CORS. Or it has to return JSONP and you have to tell jQuery to expect JSONP with `dataType: 'jsonp'`.

Comment: `dataType:'jsonp'` did it. Now it's giving trouble parsing JSON?

Comment: Because the server does not seem to return JSONP. You cannot make a cross-domain request if the server does not support it. As I said, it must either support CORS, in which case it acts just like a server on the same domain, or it must return JSONP, which is not the same as JSON. That's why you get the error. If you don't have control over the server, you have to create a proxy on your side, i.e. connect with Ajax to your server and let the server make the request to the external server.

Comment: But if I try a standard GET, I get the same unspecified error again...

Answer (score 4):

This error handler, might help you:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/example.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    cache: true,
    success: function (html) {
        alert('successful : ' + html);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            alert('Time out error.');
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            alert('Ajax request aborted.');
        } else {
            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    },
    crossDomain: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to handle the error of the function fail:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/example.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    cache: true,
    crossDomain: true
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```